# Where can I find data on method of travel to train stations?

Tags: data-request

For the UK or international. I am interested in studying how people's method of travel to/from a train station varies with station location characteristics.

Answer (score 3):

In the UK, you may be able to get this through the [National Travel Survey](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/national-travel-survey-statistics) data, though I'm not sure if it's broken down on a station-by-station basis. It looks like it may simply be regional.

Within London, I believe TfL collect more data and do so at the station-specific level - I haven't been able to find out if they release the data, as [their site](https://tfl.gov.uk/info-for/open-data-users/our-open-data) is quite vague on what's available, but I know they collect it as I remember being given a questionnaire to fill out at Kings Cross a couple of years ago! This will be quite urban-focused, though, so probably not fully suitable for your needs.